# How to concatenate 2 list strings using list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

I have 2 lists as below:

```
list1 = ['A','B']
list2 = ['C','D']
```

The required output should be `[['AC','BC'], ['AD','BD']]` using List comprehension.

Answer (score -2):

Using two for loops as a list comprehension

```
list1= ['A','B'] 
list2= ['C','D']

b=[[l+p for l in list1] for p in list2]

print(b)
```